# Calabash Android fails with No Webviews Found

Tags: android, automation, robotium, calabash

We have a fixture with embedded Webviews in each of our Activity.
On a certain page, we show a progress bar, then show the Webview, show the progress bar again, and finally load content.

Finally, we fire a Javascript query using the query method. Our fixture finally looks something like this -

```
performAction('wait_for_no_progress_bars')
performAction("wait_for_view_by_id", 'webView')
performAction('wait_for_no_progress_bars')
performAction("wait_for_view_by_id", 'webView')
result =query("webView, css:"+locator)
```

It fails at the query step saying "No Webviews found". The step before this passes (it gets the WebView), but the query step fails.
Any idea as to what could be going wrong ?

On researching into the robotium source, we found that the query method internally uses '`getCurrentViews()`' which not only looks at the visibility but also does some processing with the height. Our view here is pretty long in height. Could that cause any issues ?

The Console output is as follows -

```
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Action: wait_for_no_progress_bars - Params: 
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Action: wait_for_view_by_id - Params: webView
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Action: wait_for_no_progress_bars - Params:
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Action: wait_for_view_by_id - Params: webView
2013-01-10 14:33:42 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"","success":true}'
2013-01-10 14:33:47 - Action: query - Params: css, #payment_info
2013-01-10 14:33:48 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":["Exception stack trace:\njava.lang.RuntimeException: No webviews found\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.webview.QueryHelper.executeJavascriptInWebview(QueryHelper.java:35)\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.webview.Query.execute(Query.java:13)\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.Command.execute(Command.java:49)\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.HttpServer.runCommand(HttpServer.java:158)\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.HttpServer.serve(HttpServer.java:114)\n\tat sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.run(NanoHTTPD.java:412)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)\n"],"message":"No webviews found","success":false}'
```

And the ADB Log is as follows -

```
Activity to be started :class com.abcd.mobile.android.booking.PaymentInfoActivity
I/ActivityManager(   79): START {cmp=com.abcd.mobile.android/.booking.PaymentInfoActivity} from pid 2041
W/WindowManager(   79): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21045
W/InputManagerService(   79): Focus gain on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4169adf0 (uid=10045 pid=2041)
D/RhinoConnector( 2041): Instantiating connection for activity com.abcd.mobile.android.booking.PaymentInfoActivity
D/dalvikvm( 2041): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1892K, 13% free 27424K/31175K, paused 7ms+24ms
I/Process (   79): Sending signal. PID: 2041 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 2041): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3abcd
D/RhinoConnector( 2041): Rhino bounded. Executing post connection hook for com.abcd.mobile.android.booking.PaymentInfoActivity
I/dalvikvm( 2041): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
V/PhoneStatusBar(  152): setLightsOn(true)
I/Process (   79): Sending signal. PID: 2041 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 2041): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/System.out( 2041): URI: /
I/System.out( 2041): header: {content-type=application/json;charset=utf-8, connection=close, user-agent=Ruby, host=127.0.0.1:34777, content-length=55, accept=*/*}
I/System.out( 2041): params: {json={"command":"query","arguments":["css","#payment_info"]}
I/System.out( 2041): }
I/System.out( 2041): files: {}
I/System.out( 2041): command: {"command":"query","arguments":["css","#payment_info"]}
I/InstrumentationBackend( 2041): Got command:'Command:'Line:null,query', arguments:'[css, #payment_info]'
I/dalvikvm( 2041): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
W/System.err( 2041): java.lang.RuntimeException: No webviews found
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.webview.QueryHelper.executeJavascriptInWebview(QueryHelper.java:35)
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.webview.Query.execute(Query.java:13)
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.Command.execute(Command.java:49)
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.HttpServer.runCommand(HttpServer.java:158)
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.HttpServer.serve(HttpServer.java:114)
W/System.err( 2041):    at sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.actions.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.run(NanoHTTPD.java:412)
W/System.err( 2041):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wait_for(:timeout => 10) {query("WebView").size > 0}
```

instead of

```
performAction("wait_for_view_by_id", 'webView')
```